# How to use CASE WHEN statement with multiple id

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when

I have a problem to use CASE WHEN statement in my problem. I have data with multiple id but each multiple id have a different problem.

I want to display each problem from each same id in column not row. I tried using case when and group by but the 2nd problem not display

This is my data :

| ID | Ticket | Problem | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | A | OFF | 2020-12-30 07:00:00 |
| 400 | A | OUT | 2020-12-30 09:00:00 |
| 410 | A | OFF | 2020-12-30 09:00:00 |
| 420 | B | OUT | 2020-12-30 07:00:00 |
| 430 | B | OUT | 2020-12-30 09:00:00 |
| 430 | B | OUT | 2020-12-30 13:00:00 |

I want to display it like this

| ID | Ticket | 2020-12-30 07:00:00 | 2020-12-30 09:00:00 | 2020-12-30 13:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | A | OFF | OUT | - |
| 410 | A | - | OFF | - |
| 420 | B | OUT | - | - |
| 430 | B | OUT | - | OUT |

Thank you

Comment: Let's see your query. Also, do you intend to create dynamic columns based on the `Date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Select ticket,
       max(case when date = your_date1 then problem end) as date_1_problem,
       max(case when date = your_date2 then problem end) as date_2_problem,
       max(case when date = your_date3 then problem end) as date_3_problem
  From your_table t
Group by ticket;
```

Please note that you habe to provide the values of date1, date2 and date3 in this query.

Comment: It works. May i ask, why max works in this case?

Comment: You can use min also. It was just added as group by is used. Case when will return only one value in your case so min/max will work. Its called conditional aggregation.